# Programmatically Add Subviews to UIScrollView and Keep Constraints

Tags: objective-c, ios7, uiscrollview

I am very perplex as to how Auto Layout and Constrains are handled in iOS 7.

I have a UIView that has an embedded UIScrollView... inside that UIScrollView I have a Container View. Inside this Container View I have 3 Views...

- Label
- Content Area 1 (10 pt under Label)
- Content Area 2 (10 pt under Content Area 2)

Note: these constraints will always the same.

The label will always have the same dimensions.

When the View is first shown on the Screen both Content Area 1 and Content Area 2 are 30 pt in height with an ActivityViewSpinner spinning while 2 separate Ajax calls are made to load the data for these sections.

The data for Content Area 1 will be one of two things... either a 320x320 image or a button asking the user to submit an image.

The data for Content Area 2 will be one of two things... either a label saying there's no data or a UITableView that will be 320x300 full of data).

The use case I'm testing right now is just making the Ajax call for Content Area 1 with an image coming back... I get my Image, however, it doesn't respect the 10pt "top of content area 2 to bottom of content area 1" constraint.

I have implemented updateViewConstraints with the following code

```
    [super updateViewConstraints];


[_containerView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:otherSubmissionsView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:mySubmissionView
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                                                     multiplier:1.0
                                                       constant:10.0]];
```

However, here is what the UI looks like:

[image]

I am very perplex as to how to go about keeping this constraint in tact.

Any help would be AWESOME.